# Graphics2D Paint, not working when graphics scaled

Tags: java, java-2d

Using this class for a gradient on a rectangle
https://github.com/griffon/griffon-harmoniccode-plugin/blob/master/src/main/eu/hansolo/gradients/ContourGradientPaint.java

As soon as i enable scaling via graphics2d.setscale the box seems to not be drawn.

Im assuming this is a issue in the gradient paint but im not sure how to go about finding it.

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE]?

Comment: Mhm, it seems it is actually scaling somewhat, just seems to be completly wrong http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23077063/  http://image.prntscr.com/image/8ecc7e6fbdd4402885d58c2e6fd64f76.png

Comment: Now, one rectangle is smaller. For a scaling of 0.8 this could be right. But this doesn't mean that there might not be a bug in this gradient paint implementation. A MVCE with the actual/expected behavior could be helpful (and you might also consider reporting it as an issue on GitHub, if you assume that there may be a bug)